# ListView with alphabets on the right, like the iPhone. Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to know if a ListView in Android has an option to place alphabets on the right like the paradigm of iPhone ListView, like below

[image]

If yes, can someone provide me with sample codes.

I am not looking for the one with an Alphabet overlay from ApisDemo but an exact one like the iPhone paradigm. Is it possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I implemented somthing similar a while back so i've modified my activity and you can take a look below, sorry its not very well commented -  hope it helps!

```
  public class AZIndexer extends Activity {
    ListView myListView;
    ArrayList<String> elements;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // elements
        String s = "MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAQWERTYUIOP";
        Random r = new Random();
        elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            elements.add(s.substring(r.nextInt(s.length())));
        }
        Collections.sort(elements); // Must be sorted!

        // listview
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        MyAZAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAZAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                elements);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    class MyAZAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements SectionIndexer {
        ArrayList<String> myElements;
        HashMap<String, Integer> azIndexer;
        String[] sections;

        public MyAZAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            myElements = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
            azIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //stores the positions for the start of each letter

            int size = elements.size();
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                String element = elements.get(i);
                //We store the first letter of the word, and its index.
                azIndexer.put(element.substring(0, 1), i); 
            } 

            Set<String> keys = azIndexer.keySet(); // set of letters 

            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
            ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                keyList.add(key);
            }
            Collections.sort(keyList);//sort the keylist
            sections = new String[keyList.size()]; // simple conversion to array            
            keyList.toArray(sections);
        }

        public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
            String letter = sections[section];
            return azIndexer.get(letter);
        }

        public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
            Log.v("getSectionForPosition", "called");
            return 0;
        }

        public Object[] getSections() {
            return sections; // to string will be called to display the letter
        }
    }
}
```

With xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/myListView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the final screenshot? I don't understand how does it display the alphabets on the right of the screen. With the SectionIndexer I believe that it displays items as overlay right?

Comment: I only said it was similar! It doesn't show the alphabet on the right hand side but i dont think that would be to hard to implement, as the code i have gives you the index for the start of each letter which is what you would need. You would probably need to code you own custom listview which btw is one of the most complex views on android! Not trying to put you off, just dont see what you would gain from doing it, and i'm certainly not going to try it!  iPhones make me :( wouldnt want to copy it!

Comment: lol. ok! My client is going mad, I clearly told him that Android and iOS are two different sides of a coin. Alas! I HATE this ListView, playing with ListView is playing with fire.

Comment: I sometimes sort my lists differently, but im not able to DONt show my sectionIndexer afterwards... any ideas how to manage this?

Comment: Nice article. How to mange this if each row contain a different field (means in my list, each row need to contains name, pic, and one another textview). I have sorted the arraylist according to name. So please suggest me.

Comment: Nice example. Is there any particular reason why you create the ArrayList from the Set with the iterator instead of just using ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(keys); ?

Answer (score 23):

You can check this project https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView.
Here is the screenshot[image]

Comment: That's a nice share. I have a Question... Is it adjustable on all devices?

Comment: @EngrAnum: To my knowledge, the answer is yes. Scroller scale its size and text size depend on device. You can check in code `public IndexScroller(Context context, ListView lv) {
mDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
mScaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;`
[link](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexScroller.java#L55)

Comment: Thanks. merged two answers , the first by @Kenny and yours Jul

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you're willing to write the code, but the fast scroller as shown in the AOSP Contacts app is the platform-provided way to do present an section-indexed list.

Comment: ya I am willing to write the code, provided I get some start. I am clueless about even starting it. What is this AOSP full form.

Comment: The "fast scroll" mentioned is enabled with `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`.  You can modify the sections using a [SectionIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) implementation, such as [AlphabetIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html).  See the AOSP Contacts implementation here: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java;h=0b6fcf6148436dc009a83e336b69259c09973fa4;hb=refs/heads/master