# How to Display contact list in list view with section and header Android

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

i need to display contact list in list view with all contact type with header,selector and  slider as in iOS but not getting and demo or code [image]

i am able to read the all contact no. but i have to show contact name with contact no. like home,phone.

Comment: have you checked my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well actually, I've just finished to implement this feature in my [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) project, you can have a look, probably you will need to change something in your code, but you should also read my answer here [How can I set a listener inside a RecyclerView Header Decor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018788/how-can-i-set-a-listener-inside-a-recyclerview-header-decor)

Answer (score -1):

You can try approach described by Cyril Mottier in his [blog post](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/) to create sections in your `ListView`. Full example with code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/ListViewTipsAndTricks).

The result could look like this:

[image]

To achieve alphabet navigation like in Contacts app please follow [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349652/android-alphabets-section-listview-like-contacts-app-listview).

**Update**
Fresh alphabet navigation approach using RecyclerView was provided by [sticky-headers-recyclerview](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) library.