# creating view of default contact application in Android same as in samsung

Tags: android, contacts, expandablelistview

I am creating application in Android. We need to create view same as we have default contact application in samsung.  What i need is, i have to mention header suppose having name A under this list will contain names that starts from A and after that Header having B and under this list will contain name that start from B. Apart from this, on right side we have vertical list that starts from A , B, C, D....... upto Z. On click of this related to that character list will be opened.

Please give me your suggestion how i can achieve that feature.

Here is image![image: Creating view like this]

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Hierarchy Viewer tool to investigate how it's done. There are many tutorials on how to use it, but it's really simple.

**EDIT:**

> Michal all this thing i know, What i need is, i have to mention header suppose having name A under this list will contain names that starts from A and after that Header having B and under this list will contain name that start from B. Apart from this, on right side we have vertical list that starts from A , B, C, D....... upto Z. On click of this related to that character list will be opened. I m changing image above.

Your question says nothing about it, it's not precise. You should edit it. It's an AlphabetIndexer/SectionIndexer.

Look:

[ListView with alphabets on the right, like the iPhone. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475410/listview-with-alphabets-on-the-right-like-the-iphone-is-it-possible)

or here:

http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index#codesyntax_1

or here:

http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-android-listview.html

There are a lot of examples on the web. This examples are using fastScroller but if you want this bar with letters on the right, here you have example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548592/Android-Alphabetic-IndexBar-Scroller?display=Print

Comment: Thanks for rply. I have no idea how to implement this functionality. Can you provide me link for tutorial for creating same view.

Comment: It's a tab view and on the curent tab on the screen you have from top: a layout that contains a button and a edittext (searchbar), and a listview. That's all.

Comment: Michal all this thing i know, What i need is, i have to mention header suppose having name A under this list will contain names that starts from A and after that Header having B and under this list will contain name that start from B. Apart from this, on right side we have vertical list that starts from A , B, C, D....... upto Z. On click of this related to that character list will be opened. I m changing image above.