# How to show scroll pull in list view in android?

Tags: android

I know this could be simple but I waste lots of time to find out how to show the scroll bar in list view.

Look like this:
[image]

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it has nothing to do with indexed/sectioned ListView. Just add the `fastScrollEnabled` attribute to your ListView XML and set it to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

It is sectioned index for the listview. See this [Sample](http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index#codesyntax_1) 
and refer this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475410/listview-with-alphabets-on-the-right-like-the-iphone-is-it-possible)