# ListView with Alphabets in the right like Sony Xperia Contacts, is it possible?

Tags: android, android-listview

I searched over one day to find an example or a library that can do this for me, please see the below capture:

[image]

If you a Sony Xperia user, you exactly know what I'm asking for, as you see in the picture you user can touch the alphabetics and move it to left.
While moving further the alphabetics will be bigger.

I saw some questions on stackoverflow, but none of them matches my requirement.
And What I tried is just like regular way.

Here is the question on StackOverFlow : [ListView with alphabe....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475410/listview-with-alphabets-on-the-right-like-the-iphone-is-it-possible)  And there are many other links that I read, I can provide it too.

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: I now it's possible, can show me how ? or can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need a `ListView` with custom header support.

If you don't want to get your hand dirty and looking a much simpler solution, try this library called [SuperSLIM.](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM)

See the example below,

[image]

You can check the default example application which demonstrates the use of custom header especially in alphabetically order.

https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/tree/early_release_4/example

See the example from demo application of implement the header in alphabetic order,

```
public CountryNamesAdapter(Context context, int headerMode) {
        mContext = context;

        final String[] countryNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
        mHeaderDisplay = headerMode;

        mItems = new ArrayList<>();

        //Insert headers into list of items.
        String lastHeader = "";
        int sectionManager = -1;
        int headerCount = 0;
        int sectionFirstPosition = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < countryNames.length; i++) {
            String header = countryNames[i].substring(0, 1);
            if (!TextUtils.equals(lastHeader, header)) {
                // Insert new header view and update section data.
                sectionManager = (sectionManager + 1) % 2;
                sectionFirstPosition = i + headerCount;
                lastHeader = header;
                headerCount += 1;
                mItems.add(new LineItem(header, true, sectionManager, sectionFirstPosition));
            }
            mItems.add(new LineItem(countryNames[i], false, sectionManager, sectionFirstPosition));
        }
    }
```