# Alphabetical contact list just like android device contact list with user name and his image.

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, sectionindexer

I am sharing here a screenshot. I just want to create very same contact list here as android device contact list (here as my screenshot), that looks in alphabetical order. I tried using section indexer and without using section indexer, but it is not filterable when i'm showing image in the list. Without showing image it is working good, but when i use my own custom adapter and populate data through model, then it is not filtering the particular contacts correspond to alphabet. For example - All users name start with alphabet 'A' must be shown when we tap on that particular index of alphabets. 
 [click here to see the my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub7zE.png) 
 Please solve my problem if anybody can and share the full code to approach this.

Comment: Adding some code might be helpful

Comment: I already shared screen shot. In this screen shot, i tapped on alphabet 'M' and i am getting all names that start from alphabet 'M'. I want to implement same view with same functionality.

Comment: Google it you will find plenty tutorial ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475410/listview-with-alphabets-on-the-right-like-the-iphone-is-it-possible

Comment: Can you share here any useful link to me? :)

Comment: so solved your problem ?